# WooCommerce - Get active subscriptions in a list between start / end date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using WooCommerce subscriptions.

How can I get all subscriptions (with start date and end date) in a lists from one specific date to another date?

> Example 01/09/2016 to 15/09/2016

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by Subscription list.

Comment: HI, thank you https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/

Comment: I know what the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin is. I'm asking for clarification on your question. Do you want all subscriptions created during that time, or do you want to include subscriptions with renewal payments made during that time, The former is a simple [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) the latter I'm not sure of.

Comment: hi, i want all subscription fo rcreated during that time

Comment: Ok, so take a look at [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters), post what you try, and I'll take a look if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Do you want to export subscriptions in a limited period or just list in Subscriptions itself. If only needs list there is subscription date filter by month option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example of a function that will display a list of all active subscriptions from one date to another, in a formatted html table. In this example, you will get for each subscription: the subscription ID, the date, the customer ID and the customer name (You can customize the code to get what you want).

So this function has 2 date parameters. For usage and specifications see the section at the end.

The function code:

```
function active_subscription_list($from_date=null, $to_date=null) {

    // Get all customer orders
    $subscriptions = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', // Subscription post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-active', // Active subscription
        'orderby' => 'post_date', // ordered by date
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'date_query' => array( // Start & end date
            array(
                'after'     => $from_date,
                'before'    => $to_date,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
    ) );

    // Styles (temporary, only for demo display) should be removed
    echo "<style>
        .subscription_list th, .subscription_list td{border:solid 1px #666; padding:2px 5px;}
        .subscription_list th{font-weight:bold}
        .subscription_list td{text-align:center}
    </style>";

    // Displaying list in an html table
    echo "<table class='shop_table subscription_list'>
        <tr>
            <th>" . __( 'Number ID', 'your_theme_domain' ) . "</th>
            <th>" . __( 'Date', 'your_theme_domain' ) . "</th>
            <th>" . __( 'User ID', 'your_theme_domain' ) . "</th>
            <th>" . __( 'User Name', 'your_theme_domain' ) . "</th>
        </tr>
            ";
    // Going through each current customer orders
    foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
        $subscription_id = $subscription->ID; // subscription ID
        $subscription_date = array_shift( explode( ' ', $subscription->post_date ) ); // Date
        $subscr_meta_data = get_post_meta($subscription->ID);
        $customer_id = $subscr_meta_data['_customer_user'][0]; // customer ID
        $customer_name = $subscr_meta_data['_billing_first_name'][0] . ' ' . $subscr_meta_data['_billing_last_name'][0];
        echo "</tr>
                <td>$subscription_id</td>
                <td>$subscription_date</td>
                <td>$customer_id</td>
                <td>$customer_name</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

**USAGE** *(example)*:

You will have to respect this numerical date format: **`YEAR-MONTH-DAY`**

```
$from_date = '2016-06-19'; // start date
$to_date = '2016-09-21'; // End date

active_subscription_list($from_date, $to_date);
```

This will display a list of all active subscriptions from 2016-06-19 to 2016-09-21…

This code is tested and works.