# Unable to get all subscription in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to get **all subscriptions** list in WordPress **including active and inactive**, have tried the following function:

```
WC_Subscriptions::get_subscriptions()
```

But the problem is it always returns latest 10 records, i want to get all the records from beginning to current date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce - Get active subscriptions in a list between start / end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596477/woocommerce-get-active-subscriptions-in-a-list-between-start-end-date)

Comment: @VineetJain did i say active subscriptions?? i said All, read the question again

Comment: Remove 'post_status' then it will be for all. wasn't it? and why do you want to see inactive subscriptions?

Comment: remove the `date_query` and `post_status`, that's all you need

Comment: @Reigel from where to remove?

Comment: Have you tried: [Get all WooCommerce subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701599/get-all-woocommerce-subscriptions/45703486#45703486)

Comment: @AmrinderSingh: just comment `post_status` and `date_query` and you'll get all the subscription.

Comment: if you check `get_subscriptions` function, you will see that `WC_Subscriptions::get_subscriptions( null, array( 'numberposts' => -1 ) );` should do it. But I don't have a test environment to see why it's not.